React native state background re-render
My goal is to hide the screen of application after another app was opened and therefore my application was put to background state.
App does indeed react on background state and "loaded" is set to false. Aplication also calls for re-render. But applications screen does not change in apps view and screen stays blue but it should be black. It changes when aplication is opened once again but just for a milisecond. Same behavior is happening with functional(with useEffect) or class implementation(with mounting)
If I change state to "inactive" instead of "background" it works. But for some other reason I need to have it on "background" state. If I use class component is behavior is the same. Tried to build it directly to app not using expo-go with the same result.
Here is demo(expo online does not show logs, when app is inactive or background but its working how I described it):
expo-demo
Am I missing something or is something wrong? Quite desperate since I spent a lot of time on this.
